# Singly linked list of students in C, cannot access all fields from a node created in another function

Tags: c

I am trying to work on an exercise for a class in which we are learning C. We have to create a singly linked list of `struct STUDENT_RECORD`s. Each student record is designed to be a node in a singly linked list. Here's what the definition is:

```
struct STUDENT_RECORD{
     char *name;
     float gpa;
     int age;
     struct STUDENT_RECORD *next;
 };
```

The program I'm supposed to write takes input from the user and creates a singly linked list. Each node in the list is created from user inputs at runtime.

One of the fields of this `struct` is `name`. Since we receive input from the user from a loop that overwrites the `name` variable that stores the name input from the user, I will have to copy each name in order to have it saved in the list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "student.h"

struct STUDENT_RECORD* addNode(char* name, int anAge, float aGPA){
//this is the function that creates the new STUDENT_RECORD and returns a reference to it

//copy the input name in another string
     char nameCopy [strlen(name)+1];
     int i = 0;
     while(name[i] != '\0'){
         nameCopy[i] = name[i];
         i++;
     }
     nameCopy[strlen(name)] = '\0';

//create a new node/STUDENT_RECORD
     struct STUDENT_RECORD *ttemp = (struct STUDENT_RECORD *)malloc    (sizeof(struct STUDENT_RECORD));

//fill the new STUDENT_RECORD with input arguments
     ttemp->name = nameCopy;
     ttemp->age = anAge;
     ttemp->gpa = aGPA;
     ttemp->next = NULL;

     puts("Test to see if the data is copied right:");
     printf("%s, %d, %f\n", ttemp->name, ttemp->age, ttemp->gpa);
     return ttemp;
}


int main() {
     struct STUDENT_RECORD *head = {"dummy", 0, 0, NULL};
     char selection='Y', aName[50], garbage;
     int anAge;
     float aGPA;
     while (toupper(selection) == 'Y') {

     // prompt the user for aName[], anAge, and aGPA
         puts("Enter the student's name (up to 49 characters), age, and GPA: ");
         scanf("%s", aName);
         scanf("%d", &anAge);
         scanf("%f", &aGPA);


     struct STUDENT_RECORD *temp = addNode(aName, anAge, aGPA); 
     printf("Student created: %s, %d, %f\n", temp->name, temp-> age,temp-> gpa); //prints everything but the student name

     printf("Continue? (Y/N): ");
     //clear the buffer of the newline from the previous entry newline
     garbage = getc(stdin);
     scanf("%c", &selection);
     }

//printNodes(head);
 }
```

Now, one among the many issues I've been having with this is the fact that the pointer `*temp` does not seem to be able to see the `name` field of the `STUDENT_RECORD`. I am able to view all the others from the main, without problems. i.e., when I try to print all the fields of a returned `STUDENT_RECORD`, I get them all except the name. I don't see why this doesn't work: as far as I understand,after calling the `addNode` function, I am returned a reference to a node, and I should be able to print all its fields from the main, no?

I'm sure there are other issues too, but for now it would be a good start to at least be able to access all the fields of a given `STUDENT_RECORD` from the main function.

Thanks!!

Comment: You did not store a copy of the name.  You made a local copy and then stored a pointer to it, which became invalid the moment your function returned.  Allocate memory for your string with `malloc`.

Comment: or use `strdup` instead of malloc

Comment: `strdup` is not part of the standard C library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not store a copy of the name. You made a local copy and then stored a pointer to it, which became invalid the moment your function returned.

This is why your test inside the function showed no problem.  After the function returned, using that pointer resulted in undefined behavior.

Allocate memory for your string with `malloc`:

```
char *nameCopy = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
if (nameCopy) strcpy(nameCopy, name);
```

Remember to `free` this memory later when you get around to deleting your nodes.

Comment: why do we remove nameCopy totally? malloc on ttemp->name and copy between nameCopy and ttemp->name. Is it better?

Comment: @paddy Thanks, that totally worked for me. One question about freeing the memory again: I know I'll have to free it eventually, but do I free it inside the function that allocates it? If I do that, don't I lose any data I just set aside? By "when you get around to deleting your nodes, do you mean when I no longer need the list anymore?

Comment: @LocTran it doesn't really make a difference, and is a matter of style and taste.  In this case, it's a minimal solution for an isolated piece of code to match the original post.

Comment: @P.Gillich you free it when you no longer need the memory.  Doing this inside `addNode` is a bizarre notion, when the whole purpose of that function is to create the node.  I am talking about when you remove nodes from the list and want to release their allocated memory.  Or possibly if you want to replace the string in a node with a different one.

Comment: @paddy I realize it's a silly notion, I guess I shouldn't have asked. I guess my thought was that I would need to free up whatever I allocated eventually, lest this program hog all my memory even when it isn't  running. I guess it doesn't work like that.

Comment: It's fine to ask.  I just wanted to point out that it didn't make sense.  Modern operating systems will return any unreleased memory back to the system when your program exits.  This wasn't always the case, and it was possible for badly-behaved programs to leak system memory on exit.  Nowadays, cleaning up properly is more a case of good manners (not to mention good style).